# export dataframe to excel but I came across printing problem

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append

I want to export my dataframe that is created differently in everyday to same excel everyday. When I create new dataframe, I read the fixed excel file and append my new dataframe to older one and then I export the final dataframe to excel but I can not solve the printing problem.

When I print my dataframe before export the excel, my dataframe is smooth. ı guess, I made mistake at last part.

I can print new dataframes like this:

```
print(BUY)
print(SELL)

Output:

date
2019-08-17 00:00:00    0
2019-08-17 01:00:00    0
2019-08-17 02:00:00    0
2019-08-17 03:00:00    0
2019-08-17 04:00:00    0
2019-08-17 05:00:00    0
2019-08-17 06:00:00    0
2019-08-17 07:00:00    0
2019-08-17 08:00:00    0
2019-08-17 09:00:00    0
2019-08-17 10:00:00    0
2019-08-17 11:00:00    0
2019-08-17 12:00:00    0
2019-08-17 13:00:00    0
2019-08-17 14:00:00    0
2019-08-17 15:00:00    0
2019-08-17 16:00:00    0
2019-08-17 17:00:00    0
2019-08-17 18:00:00    0
2019-08-17 19:00:00    0
2019-08-17 20:00:00    0
2019-08-17 21:00:00    0
2019-08-17 22:00:00    0
2019-08-17 23:00:00    0

date
2019-08-17 00:00:00    17.0
2019-08-17 01:00:00    15.3
2019-08-17 02:00:00    12.5
2019-08-17 03:00:00    12.2
2019-08-17 04:00:00    12.9
2019-08-17 05:00:00    13.7
2019-08-17 06:00:00    16.3
2019-08-17 07:00:00    16.4
2019-08-17 08:00:00    14.7
2019-08-17 09:00:00    16.3
2019-08-17 10:00:00    13.6
2019-08-17 11:00:00    12.1
2019-08-17 12:00:00    11.7
2019-08-17 13:00:00    38.1
2019-08-17 14:00:00    41.3
2019-08-17 15:00:00    43.5
2019-08-17 16:00:00    43.9
2019-08-17 17:00:00    48.0
2019-08-17 18:00:00    50.1
2019-08-17 19:00:00    52.3
2019-08-17 20:00:00    50.9
2019-08-17 21:00:00    50.6
2019-08-17 22:00:00    46.7
2019-08-17 23:00:00    45.4
```

But, I want to append these to older one and write some code for it:

```
df_BUY = pd.read_excel(pure_path + "pure_dam_buy.xlsx", index_col = 0)
df_SELL = pd.read_excel(pure_path + "pure_dam_sell.xlsx", index_col = 0)


df_BUY = df_BUY.append(BUY, sort=False)
df_SELL = df_SELL.append(SELL, sort=False)


df_BUY.to_excel(pure_path + "pure_dam_buy.xlsx", index= True)
df_SELL.to_excel(pure_path + "pure_dam_sell.xlsx", index = True)
```

When I run this, I get transpose of the data. Dates become column headers. How can I handle this?

Comment: Can you print `df_BUY` after you append `BUY` to it? 

I just replicated your code and it wrote to excel as expected.

Comment: Is there problem in my excel?

Comment: I think it's a problem with the DataFrame after `df_BUY = df_BUY.append(BUY, sort=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Check your dataframe right after `df_BUY = df_BUY.append(BUY, sort=False)`
OR try [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

## Code

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-08-17 23:00:00',0],['2019-08-18 23:00:00',0],
['2019-08-19 23:00:00',0],['2019-08-20 23:00:00',0]], columns=['date',''])

df.to_excel(r'C://Users/user_name/Desktop/pure_dam_buy.xlsx', index=True)
```

## **Output**

[image: Excel Output]